# MS Power APPS - Add timestamp to a Record

Tags: timestamp, powerapps

I am try to make a volunteer Check in App in MS Power Apps, I have figured out how to add a timestamp to a record. Like, when I hit the Sign in button it adds the time into the "Check_x0020_IN" record. But it adds the time to the first person on the list. How can I make it so I can select any person and have a time added to them? I've attached images of what I got: [Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cKUu.jpg)

[OnSelect code for Sign In Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sftw9.jpg)

Also how can I make the button disappear after they have signed in?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

About Changing the visibility of the button after clicking on it you can create an updateContext {myButtonVisible : true} , and initially at the visibility of the screen set it to true, and when you OnSelect that button, you can set it now to false. You can then use this value for you button's Visible field.

For updating the fields in excel sheet check this tutorial : https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/get-started-create-from-blank/

Thanks,
Eman